# excel macro tecla enter

Tags: excel, macros

Intento hacer una **macro** que se ejecute al pulsar **Enter**. La idea es que al pulsar la tecla Enter, cree una fila nueva con un valor ***autonumérico***. El problema es que al grabar la macro, esta coge los ***rangos***. ¿Hay alguna forma para que la macro siempre salte a la celda de la primera columna de la siguiente fila a la actual? ¿Y de ejecutarla con la tecla Enter? Gracias.

Comment: Disculpa, no entiendo eso de *salte a la celda de la primera columna de la siguiente fila a la actual* ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo?

Comment: Otra cosa, desconozco tus necesidades pero en ningún caso recomiendo asignar una macro a una tecla como Enter, que ya tiene unas funciones determinadas en Excel. ¿Por qué tiene que ser la tecla Enter y no otra?

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes gracias por tu respuesta. Me piedieron que grabara una macro que al rellenar datos en una fila y pulsar ENTER, salte a la siguiente fila rellenando la primera celda con un autonum'erico (=FILA()-7 en mi caso) y poner el foco en la celda de su derecha. No sé si es posible. Aún siento otra tecla distinta a enter, cómo puedo hacer para los rangos? Ya que siempre me salta a la celda en la que grabé la macro. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Este código insertará la fórmula `FILA()-7` en la columna A, y automáticamente seleccionará la celda adyacente en la columna B. Yo he jugado con la columna A y B pero adapta el código a tus necesidades:

```
Sub NUEVA_FILA()
Range("A" & (Range("A" & Range("A:A").Count).End(xlUp).Row) + 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=ROW()-7"
Range("B" & (Range("A" & Range("A:A").Count).End(xlUp).Row)).Select
End Sub
```

Esto es lo que yo consigo ejecutando el código varias veces.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, mi macro no está asignada a ninguna tecla ni atajo de teclado. Yo lo he hecho insertando un botón (control ActiveX) en la hoja, y al hacer clic, ejecuta la macro.

> Para saber más sobre insertar botones en hojas, **[haz clic
>   aquí](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/asignar-una-macro-a-un-bot%C3%B3n-formulario-o-control-d58edd7d-cb04-4964-bead-9c72c843a283)**

Comment: Así es como terminé haciéndolo yo también, con un botón. Igualmente, gracias por tu comentario! Lo voto porque es una buena alternativa.